# Query with array in condition in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have 2 tabs:

- Overview with the list of tasks and columns per each day when they should be done. The task can be open or completed several times.
- Wall of shame - it should consist of Open tasks which deadline is over. The deadline should be filled in from line 1 in the Overview tab. If the task is overdue several times it should be specified as a new line with the new deadline.

I need help with the formula for "Wall of shame" tab.
Please see my example - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gaH-XCf9JtM0C2pJU9EidOk1hsLhmZ5J_b-5_0JUgyc/edit#gid=113767391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `A1`, deleting everything else in the 'Wall of Shame' sheet:

```
=arrayformula(
query({"Department"\"Activity"\"Owner"\"Deadline"\"Date open"\"Overdue, days";
query({
flatten(split(rept("|"&Overview!A2:A;columns(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0)));"|"))\
flatten(split(rept("|"&Overview!B2:B;columns(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0)));"|"))\
flatten(split(rept("|"&Overview!C2:C;columns(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0)));"|"))\
flatten(split(rept("|"&Overview!E2:E;columns(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0)));"|"))\
flatten(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0))\
if(flatten(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0))<>"";today()-flatten(query(iferror(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(if(Overview!F2:AA="Open";if(Overview!F1:AA1<=today();Overview!F$1:AA$1;);));"";9^9)));" "););"";0));)
};"where Col6 is not null ";0)};
"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6";1))
```

I've put the whole thing in a query so you can decide which columns you want to select, ie, you could adapt to `select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col6`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please also tell me how to remove completed tasks from this list? I also need to add the following condition - If there are 2 open tasks, the list should contain 2 lines with 2 different dates. Is it possible?

Comment: No probs - solution updated.

Comment: Now it shows the list of open tasks but only 1 record per task. Could you update it to show each time when the task was not completed?
E.g. The 1st task of Salg department is open on 11/09 and 12/09. It should be specified twice in this list. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try the update.

Comment: Thanks. Сan the formula work dynamically without adding ColX?

Comment: I've redone the formula. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237224/discussion-between-maksym-katsovets-and-aresvik).